# Display different image formats in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am new to javascript. If question is wrong 
I have different image formats in a folder.

How can display all images?
code to read .jpg is given below. I need to include other image formats like .JPG,.png etc..

```
$ps_albums.children('div').bind('click',function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    var index=parseInt($elem.index());
    var folder_no=elems-index;
    var album_name  = 'albums/album' + folder_no;
    var j=0;
    var dir=album_name;
    var d1=album_name+"/";
    var fileextension=".JPG";
    var f1=".jpg";
    var f2=".png";
    //var f3=".PNG";

    $loading    = $('<div />',{className:'loading'});
    $elem.append($loading);
    $ps_container.find('img').remove();


    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        var d=d1+(i+1)+f1;
        data1[i]=d;
    }
    //alert(data1);
    var items_count = data1.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < items_count; ++i){
        var item_source = data1[i];
        var cnt         = 0;
        var img=new Image();
        var title=$('span')[index].innerHTML;
        $('<img />').load(function(){
            var $image = $(this);

            ++cnt;
            resizeCenterImage($image);
            $ps_container.append($image);

            var r       = Math.floor(Math.random()*41)-20;
            if(cnt < items_count){
                $image.css({
                    '-moz-transform'    :'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform' :'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                    'transform'         :'rotate('+r+'deg)'
                });
            }
            if(cnt == items_count){
                $loading.remove();
                $ps_container.show();
                $ps_close.show();
                $ps_play.show();
                //$ps_pause.show();
                $ps_overlay.show();
            }

        }).attr('src',item_source,'title',title);

    }   
});
```

This function is used to display images when click a button
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
//before  adding

if(validateImage(currentImage)){

//Add to Data1

}else{
//alert("Only .jpg, .jpeg,.png, .gif  files are allowed!");
console.log("Only .jpg, .jpeg,.png, .gif  files are allowed!");

}

     function validateImage(currentImage) {

                //Regular Expression for fileupload control.
                var reg = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif)$/;
                if (currentImage.length > 0) {
                    //Checks with the control value.
                    if (reg.test(currentImage)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        //If the condition not satisfied shows error message.
                        //alert("Only .jpg, .jpeg,.png, .gif  files are allowed!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } //End of function validate.
```

Comment: I need to get currect image format. That is for eg: 1.jpg,2.png etc.. both should store to variable data1[i].

Comment: yes use this validate function pass the current image as a
parameter to the function if the function returns true store it to variable else display alert...

Comment: SHASHANK@: it returns false. I couldn't understand about var reg. Is it contains only image name or pathname.?

Comment: var reg is a regural expression which checks whether the uploaded file is of jpg,gif,png..format..
it returns true if the file uploaded is of the following format else returns false..